# How to change Solr document id by SolrJ?

Tags: solr

I use the following code to change specific field value.

```
SolrInputDocument solrdoc=new SolrInputDocument();
solrdoc.addField("id","book001");
Map<String,Object> fieldModifier=new HashMap<>(1);
fieldModifier.put("set","book_new_name");
solrdoc.addField("name",fieldModifier);
```

But I cannot use the similar code to change Solr unique document id, exception is thrown.

```
solrdoc.addField("id",fieldModifier);
```

Is there any solution to change the Solr document id?

Comment: In my case, I need to modify a lot of document ids, and each of the documents contains a large content inside. So I don't want to re-add them for performance issues.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the document id requires removing and re-adding the document, so delete the document (by id), then re-add the document with the new id. You can do this without committing between deleting and adding the document, so it will be seamless for any clients querying the collection.

Comment: Do the following piece codes match what you say?
`solrClient.deleteByQuery("id:book001”);`
`SolrInputDocument document=new SolrInputDocument();`
`document.addField("id:book002”);`
`solrClient.add(document);`
`solrClient.commit();`
I doubt that when invoke deleteByQuery() function, solr client also gets response at the same time. Could you show me the code if I am wrong.

Comment: Try it! I'm currently not using SolrJ, but it seems to be OK.