# How to modify a doc in solr containing an auto generated unique id

Tags: solr

I am using signatureupdateprocessorfactory to generate unique key "id".

```
<processor class="solr.processor.SignatureUpdateProcessorFactory">
  <bool name="enabled">true</bool>
  <str name="signatureField">id</str>
  <bool name="overwriteDupes">true</bool>
  <str name="fields">image_link</str>
  <str name="signatureClass">solr.processor.Lookup3Signature</str>
```

The doc I want to modify is :

```
<doc>
<str name="title">47107</str>
<str name="id">6e004034dafc9f11</str>
<long name="_version_">1528941445348589568</long>
<str name="image_link">xyz.jpeg</str>
</doc>
```

I am using solrj to modify the document .

```
SolrInputDocument sdoc = new SolrInputDocument();
sdoc.addField("id","6e004034dafc9f11");
Map<String,Object> fieldModifier = new HashMap<>(1);
fieldModifier.put("set","47100");
sdoc.addField("title", fieldModifier);  // add the map as the field value

server.add( sdoc );  // send it to the solr server

server.commit();
```

this shows an error

```
Document contains multiple values for uniqueKey field: id=[6e004034dafc9f11, 0000000000000000]
```

If I use

```
<processor class="solr.UUIDUpdateProcessorFactory" />
```

which generates uuid for id field.
Then another doc is added similar to the doc to be modified. Again which is not desirable.

But when I do not use auto generated unique id .This code works fine. i.e. while adding the doc I specify the id field also.
the code is:

```
SolrInputDocument sdoc = new SolrInputDocument();
  sdoc.addField("id","1");
  Map<String,Object> fieldModifier = new HashMap<>(1);
  fieldModifier.put("set","47101");
  sdoc.addField("title", fieldModifier);  // add the map as the field value

  server.add( sdoc );  // send it to the solr server

  server.commit();
```

there is a similar question here [Solr: How to update a document with unique ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25826278/solr-how-to-update-a-document-with-unique-id).

How can I do this using auto generated unique id . Is it possible. If yes then please help.Thanks

Comment: Has your id field in the schema.xml the attribute mulitvalued="true" ?

Comment: Maybe this answer helps: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19060114/292352

Comment: <field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" />

Comment: The answer  here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19060114/292352  is for updating the unique id but I do not want to update the unique id. i just want to change some other field corresponding that unique id.

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36010070/292352

Comment: I have found a JIRA issue on the same: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-4016